# Auto Submit in Formtastic using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I want to able to auto-submit my form once the input field 'studentnumber' reaches 8. 
but i am not very familiar with jquery, and I don't really know where to start. 
I tried to do this my self, but from what i understand Jquery/javascript uses Id and class ?

I also found the following function, and tried it out but i think i am doing this the wrong way.

```
$('#____').keyup(function(){
if(this.value.length ==8){
$('#___').click();
}
});
```

My form looks like this.

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@event, @student] do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do %>
<%= f.input :event, :label => "Select Your Event", :include_blank => false %>
<%= f.input :studentnumber, :label => "Student Number", :input_html => {:autofocus => true} %>
<% end %>

<%= f.actions do %>
<%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any feedback would be very appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

If any one is looking for answers, 
I had do few different things, since i had 2 submit buttons in my app i just ended up using the input[name="student[studentnumber] instead of #id 
And i had to use the .trigger method instead of .submit since i had 2 submits on the same page.

the final script looks like this

```
$('input[name="student[studentnumber]"]').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val().length ==8)
  $('input[name="commit"]').trigger('click');});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're on the right track, but instead of `$("#___").click()`, you should submit the form instead of invoking click on something.

Also, in your `if` statement, you are using a DOM element, when you should be using a jQuery object. `$(this)` as opposed to `this`

`$("form#theForm").submit()`
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Final code would look like,

```
$('#text_field').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).value.length ==8)
    $('form#myForm').submit();
});
```

Also, i wanted to note that since you are using rails, you should use Coffee.  It's much nicer.

Comment: hey so I tried do the following 
' $('input[name="student[studentnumber]"]').keypress(function(){
   if($(this).val().length ==8)
  $('input[name="commit"]').trigger('click');
}); '

It works when it reaches 9 characters 
how can i make it work when it reaches 8 ?